# Does ng-input-tags actually filter results?

Tags: angularjs

When using the autocomplete feature with [ng-input-tags](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) the list of available tags does not filter at all meaning that it just displays the source options in the order they are received. This is really confusing because it means if you have more than the limit of options you have set to show and type 'b' then all of the options that start with 'a' are shown first and you'll never see anything that starts with 'b'. Am I missing an option or something?

Example options code

```
tags: [
          {text: 'a1'},
          {text: 'a2'},
          {text: 'a3'},
          {text: 'a4'},
          {text: 'a5'},
          {text: 'a6'},
          {text: 'a7'},
          {text: 'a8'},
          {text: 'a9'},
          {text: 'a10'},
          {text: 'b1'},
          {text: 'b2'},
          {text: 'b3'},
          {text: 'b4'},
          {text: 'b5'},
          {text: 'b6'},
          {text: 'b7'},
          {text: 'b8'},
          {text: 'b9'},
          {text: 'b10'},
          {text: 'b11'},
          {text: 'b12'},
        ]
```

And what it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official site of ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted),

> **IMPORTANT**: The autocomplete directive does not perform any filtering whatsoever. It provides your code with the text typed by the user so you can return a matching list of suggestions by using an appropriate solution for your application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the **default minimum length** has been set to **3** by the author of the library:
[Reference](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/d70f00ad09154b6216fcdc5c30752d77fca5ac47/src/auto-complete.js#L17)

You would have to specify the minLength yourself if you want to make that work by adding the attribute `min-length="1"` in your html.

Answer (score 0):

The [ng-input-tags](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api) shows all the data in the tags, auto-completion shows all the elements in tag but the searched data will be **in bold font**. To trigger auto-completion by default the **minimum length** is set to **3**, in your case to trigger the auto-completion you need to change it to `min-length="1"`.

For demo you can view [demo](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos). If you type any other 3 characters other than Tag, then also whole tags data is shown, but the difference is only that they are **not in bold font**.